# How to make an action in an application whenever a certain text appears in it

Tags: debugging, automation, testing, ui-automation

I have an application and I would like to debug its input/output behaviour the same way I can do in a Web environment with Selenium. Do you know any easy to use application for this matter?

Comment: What kind of application?  What is it written with?  What non-web languages do you know?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Ross, but I don't understand the exact meaning of your questions. I don't know in which language the application is programmed. It is a desktop application for Windows XP. I program in C, C++, Java.

I appreciate your responding to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Microsoft UI Automation. If it's a Microsoft app or written recently then chances are some patterns will be supported.

White ( http://white.codeplex.com ) and WiPFlash ( http://code.google.com/p/WiPFlash ) are both wrappers around Microsoft UI Automation. White may also support some legacy apps built on WinForms.

Snoop UI ( http://blois.us/Snoop/ ) will give you an idea of the kind of thing you can do with the app. You're looking for things like InvokePattern, ValuePattern and TextPattern being supported on the components you want to use. The NameProperty may also give you some useful information. If they're not there then Microsoft UI automation won't help you, at which point I give up with apologies.